# Conditionally Adding String in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am currently stuck with a very simple yet confusing issue while using StringTokenizer. What I am trying to achieve is below:

I have a URL String as:

```
http://xxx:port/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='TP' AND
(status='Ready for INT Deployment' or status = 'Ready for UAT Deployment')
```

Above is the base string. Now I want to dynamically add more query parameters to the above URL as below:

```
"AND (key=NN-1234 OR key=NN-4321 OR key=NN-65343.....)"
```

Here is my code:

```
private String getPartialIssueList() {
    String listFromProperties = getPropertyValue("propagateList");
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(listFromProperties, ",");
    StringBuilder partialListString = new StringBuilder();
    partialListString.append(" AND key=");

    while (token.hasMoreElements()) {
        partialListString.append(token.nextElement() + " OR key=" + token.nextElement());
    }
    return partialListString.toString();
}
```

Somehow this only works if I have 2 inputs. What I want is, after the base url an "AND" should be added followed by opening brackets "(" and then key="value from properties", value 2 from properties, value 3 from properties, then closing brace ")". Irrespective of how many JIRA ID's I have in properties file, it should keep on adding "OR key=NN-5432 OR key="NN-9875" and so on..

This is the output I am looking for:

```
http://xxx:port/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='TP' AND 
(status='Ready for INT Deployment' or status = 'Ready for UAT Deployment') AND 
(key=NN-09876 OR key=NN-09873 OR key=NN-09376 OR key=NN-02876)
```

Currently values for propagateList in the properties file is

```
propagateList="NN-09876","NN-65432","NN-65430"
```

Can someone please help out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separately prepare key conditions.

```
private String getPartialIssueList() {
    String listFromProperties = getPropertyValue("propagateList");
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(listFromProperties, ",");
    StringBuilder partialListString = new StringBuilder();
    partialListString.append(" AND ");
    partialListString.append("(");

    // Prepare key condition
    StringBuilder orKeys = new StringBuilder();
    while(token.hasMoreElements()) {
        // Replace token.nextToken() to token.nextToken().replaceAll("\"", "") if you don't want quotes
        orKeys.append("key=" + token.nextToken() + " OR ");
    }
    // Remove last "OR" and concatenate 
    partialListString.append(orKeys.toString().replaceAll(" OR $", ""));
    partialListString.append(")");

    return partialListString.toString();
}
```

Result:

```
System.out.println(getPartialIssueList());
AND (key="NN-09876" OR key="NN-65432" OR key="NN-65430")
```

Now, concatenate base URL to you dynamical query:

```
String base = "http://xxx:port/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='TP' AND (status='Ready for INT Deployment' or status = 'Ready for UAT Deployment')";
base += getPartialIssueList();
System.out.println(base);
------------------------------------------
http://xxx:port/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='TP' AND 
(status='Ready for INT Deployment' or status = 'Ready for UAT Deployment') AND 
(key="NN-09876" OR key="NN-65432" OR key="NN-65430")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thank you so much. I was missing the removal of the last OR. Your help worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with these changes and it works fine. Please let me know if it is something wrong.

```
private String getPartialIssueList() {
    String listFromProperties = getPropertyValue("propagateList");
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(listFromProperties, ",");
    StringBuilder partialListString = new StringBuilder();
    partialListString.append(" AND (key="); // updated with ( 

    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) { // used tokens as it is a string
        partialListString.append(token.nextToken() + " OR key=" + token.nextElement());
    }
    partialListString.append(")"); // added closed bracket
    return partialListString.toString();
}

private String getPropertyValue(String propagateList) { // list is seperated by commas
    return "'Ready for INT Deployment', 'Ready for UAT Deployment'";
}
```

Comment: Here is the the output.    `AND (key='Ready for INT Deployment' OR key= 'Ready for UAT Deployment')`

Comment: Have you  tried this 3 or 5 values? I think this will fail as its exactly what I had code with addition of appending ")" in the end.

Comment: I tried with the input you provided but not with 3 or 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives the output that you expected

```
    private static String getPartialIssueList() {
           String listFromProperties = "NN-09876, NN-65432, NN-65430";
           StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(listFromProperties, ",");
           StringBuilder partialListString = new StringBuilder();
           partialListString.append(" AND key=");

           while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {

               partialListString.append(token.nextToken());
               if(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    partialListString.append(" OR key=" );
               } else {
                    break;
                 }
           }
           return partialListString.toString();
    }
```

The method **nextElement()** should be called after seeing if there is a next element using **hasMoreElements()**. Your code works only with even numbered inputs because after every check it invokes **nextElement()** twice so if there are two elements after the check it works and if there is only one the first invocation works and the second throws NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Thanks Dev. Like the accepted answer, this too gets me the results I need. However, when I compared the performance of both, accepted answer works faster. Is it because of additional check in the while loop?